# XSLT Form Post asks to save the file instead of displaying results or navigating page

Tags: xml, forms, xslt-2.0

Am trying to send data to server using Form Post from XSLT. It's sending all the details to server without any issue and server update the database with the form data but it's displaying a download page after server response.

Here is my sample XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-16"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form name="myForm" method="post" action="/MyServlet">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="10"
                            > </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="address" rows="2" cols="10"
                            > </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:element name="input">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="type">submit</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">Submit</xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:element name="input">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="type">Reset</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">Cancel</xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I click Submit button, am able to retrieve details at the server end but it's displaying page download. May I know the issue with the form submit ?

It's asking me to save the file instead of navigating to home page.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet, `/MyServlet`, needs to have the following characteristics:

- A response returned via HTTP or HTTPS
- A response body with content which is a HTML, XML, or plain text document
- A content type of `text/html`, `text/plain`,`text/xml`, `application/xml`, or `application/xhtml+xml`

**References**

- [IE and the Accept Header](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/01/ie-and-the-accept-header.aspx)
- [MIME-Handling Changes in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/26/mime-handling-changes-in-internet-explorer.aspx)
- [Mozilla Web Developer FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ)
- [Content Negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation)